# Unexpected system freezes

Tags: 14.04, freeze

The title is pretty self-explanatory: every once in a while, my system (14.04 x64) freezes: the mouse isn't moving, REISUB does nothing and all I can do is cut off the power supply.

I guess this can be a hardware issue (my computer has a long history of breaking, it's like a curse), but I am a Linux newbie and I don't have any idea where to look.

Thanks in advance for help :)

Comment: REISUB not working sounds like a kernel panic. Can you give us info on your build? Did you do anything with the kernel?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bad hard drive possibly. I'd recommend running a hard drive scan to find the health of your machine. Typically freezing of the mouse and slowness (specifically on computers with a history like this) is caused by hardware not software. Good luck!